# How to mitigate/stop voltage spikes when turning AC transformer on and off

Tags: voltage, transformer, ac, spike

I wish to use a certain transformer in a project of mine but when I power the transformer on or off I see a series of large voltage spikes on the oscilloscope.

The project is a DC power supply.  The transformer takes 230vac mains and steps down to 20vac then that gets rectified and etc., etc..  The transformer alone is generating these spikes and they appear to come from RF radiation from the transformer itself.

The spikes can be as large as 39Vpp.  Each "spike" is actually a decreasing amplitude voltage oscillation where the frequency is quite high (>20Mhz/see screen shots).

These spikes are bad and will certainly cause the CPU that I am going to use in my project to fail.

The transformer is a Triad Magnetics FP20-2400 (PC Mount: Flat Pack) power transformer, 230VAC primary to 20VAC secondary.

I have done a lot of research and I am still unclear how to stop these.

I've seen that these spikes are possibly caused by powering up/down the transformer at an inopportune moment in the 60hz mains cycle.  Is that the cause?  If so, would using a TRIAC fix the issue?  How would I implement this on an AC transformer with significant secondary winding load (~6A sustained)?

Something that confuses me is in my research I have seen that these types of spikes are caused by back EMF when the power to the transformer is turned off.  But I see these spikes when turning the transformer on too.

I have tried fully encasing the transformer in a grounded metal box, low pass filters (3db point @ 1.6Khz), and snubber circuits across the secondary coil and nothing works well enough.  I still have large enough spikes of about 14Vpp.

So I need some help here.

I would like to know what is causing these spikes and how to reduce them to acceptable levels (<0.3Vpp) or even to prevent the spikes from happening in the first place.  An example circuit would be greatly appreciated.

I have provided some screen shots of the problem from the oscilloscope.

Pic #1: Main body of spikes occurs ~50us after switch is turned on.
Pic #2: Zoomed in on a few of the spikes.
Pic #3: Zoomed in further on just one "spike", it is a decreasing amplitude voltage oscillation.

Thanks in advance,
Pat

[image: Voltage Spikes - Overall view]

[image: Voltage Spikes - Zoomed in a bit]

[image: Voltage Spike - Zoomed in to one "spike"]

Comment: How do you know the oscilloscope is not lying to you? What happens when you turn the lights on and off in the room?

Comment: How do you know that these spikes are "bad" and will cause your project to fail? How do you know that the spikes are not actually being **created** by some other part of your project?

Comment: Where in your test setup is the scope probe connected? At the transformer secondary?

Comment: Voltage spikes are common when the transformer is switched off due to the interruption of the circuit current (the transformer is an inductor and the current cannot vary instantly, to interrupt suddenly, there must be a voltage spike). When reconnecting the transformer, it is common to have a peak current (called inrush current) that is caused by the difference between the residual magnetic flux and the flux required at the time of energization. I don't see exactly how the connection of the circuit transformer can generate the voltage spikes.

Comment: @Kartman  Thanks for the reply.  These spikes only happen when I turn the  transformer on or off.  Just to be sure though, I left the oscilloscope on Pass/Fail mode for over 12 hours with a tight +/-1V mask.  I turned on and off virtually everything in my house.  It never failed.  I then turned the transformer on and it failed the first time (12Vpp).  It is the transformer.  I just need some advice on how to mitigate these spikes....

Comment: @Elliot Anderson   Thanks for your reply.  I actually don't but the datasheet lists the PIC16F690 max voltage at Vdd to be -0.3 to 6.5 relative to Vss.  I am getting well above this repeatedly.  Should that not eventually make the CPU fail?    Also, I have isolated the transformer.  It is not connected to anything but the mains.  When I power the transformer on or off about 50% of the time I get these spikes.  It does not matter where or how I connect the oscilloscope.  It can be left floating or I can connect to the rest of the circuit.  I still get the spikes.

Comment: @AJN I have tried connecting the scope probes at various places and they include the transformer secondary, at Vdd of the CPU, and just left floating.  I get the spikes everywhere and on both scope channels at the same exact instant.  I believe it must be EMI from the transformer radiating RF.  That is all I can conclude.

Comment: The transformer is not directly connected to your PIC, so why the comparison? There should be a bridge rectifier, capacitor and regulator. Do you get the glitch on the output of the regulator? 
You might want to get an isolation transformer for your scope to rule out earth bounce causing the scope to lie to you.

Comment: @Luiz Oliveira  Thanks for your reply.  Yes, so there are two possible causes?  One from inrush current and the other from back EMF from the collapse of the field?  OK, so I am confused too.  I don't see other people having huge problems with voltage spikes like this.  I actually have another transformer from a different manufacturer and it does the same thing but a little less severe.  So I do not know how to approach this.  The snubber circuit across the secondary does nothing, no effect.  The biggest effect is encasing the transformer in a grounded metal box.  But not enough...

Comment: @Katman  Yes, the PIC is ready to go.  Right now I use a LM7805 voltage regulator for Vdd for the PIC.  I was checking that power and I observed the spikes.  Yes, I get the spikes everywhere; at the secondary, at the rectifiier DC output, after the 4700uF cap, and at the output of the LM7805, and crucially when the scope probes are left floating.  Everywhere.  Doesn't that mean it is EMI from radiative RF?  Further, if I encase the transformer in a grounded metal box the amplitude is significantly reduced, but not enough.  I am very confused here and I don't know where to go from here...

Comment: @Katman  Actually I have a large step down transformer that I use to convert 230vac to 115vac.  Could I use that?  Would that isolate the power for the scope?

Comment: @Katman OK, I ran my oscilloscope off of the transformer and I still get voltage spikes when turning the transformer on and off.  I will go ahead and connect the PIC circuit to the rest of the circuit.  If it fails I will post another question.  But these voltage spikes greatly exceed the absolute maximum voltage rating for Vdd of the PIC CPU.

Comment: Generally, if anyone has suggestions for inrush current, snubber, or filter circuits to control these voltage spikes coming from the transformer I would appreciate the suggestions.  Or perhaps even a different transformer?  Thanks in advance...

Comment: Dear @Pat, can you post a schematic showing how is your circuit (where is the transformer relative to the source and where are you measuring the voltage)?